# Check the diagonal neighbors of a node

Tags: javascript, algorithm, multidimensional-array, cells

I'm trying to compare the values of a node. Using the flood-fill algorithm I was able to check vertically and horizontally every node of my grid. Now I have to update my code to check the cells that sit on the diagonal, as in the image below:

[image]

In red you have the current node, in yellow are the cells that need to be checked.

Here is a snippet of what I have so far:

```
var mapWidth = Math.sqrt(mapData.length);
var currentCell = $('[data-x="'+ x +'"][data-y="'+ y +'"]');
if (x < 0 || y < 0 || x > mapWidth || y > mapWidth) {
    return;
}
if(mapData[x*mapWidth+y] !== 0 || currentCell.hasClass('cell-grey')) {
    if(mapData[x*mapWidth+y] > 0) {
        currentCell.addClass('cell-grey').css('opacity', '1');
    }
    if(mapData[(x-1)*mapWidth+(y-1)] > 0 && mapData[(x-1)*mapWidth+(y-1)] < mapWidth) {
        currentCell.addClass('cell-grey').css('opacity', '1');
        return;
    }
    if(mapData[(x-1)*mapWidth+(y+1)] > 0 && mapData[(x-1)*mapWidth+(y+1)] < mapWidth) {
        currentCell.addClass('cell-grey').css('opacity', '1');
        return;
    }
    if(mapData[(x+1)*mapWidth+(y-1)] > 0 && mapData[(x+1)*mapWidth+(y-1)] < mapWidth) {
        currentCell.addClass('cell-grey').css('opacity', '1');
        return;
    }
    if(mapData[(x+1)*mapWidth+(y+1)] > 0 && mapData[(x+1)*mapWidth+(y+1)] < mapWidth) {
        currentCell.addClass('cell-grey').css('opacity', '1');
        return;
    }
    return true;
}
```

`mapWidth` is the variable that contains all the cells of the grid, and `currentCell` is the current node cell. This snippet is not really working for me.

Comment: If you have code that works for lateral moves, there is no reason it doesn't work for diagonal ones after minimal update. Can we see the other code ?

Comment: "not really working" is not informative. Can you say more ?

Comment: By not really working, I mean the diagonal neighbors are not checked

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you evaluate `mapData[(x-1)*mapWidth+(y-1)]`, the values of `x-1` and `y-1` may cause an out-of-bounds reference, which returns `undefined`. You have to validate the cell coordinates before accessing the array.

You can iterate over the four diagonal neighbors like this:

```
for (var neighborX = x - 1; neighborX <= x + 1; neighborX += 2) { 
    if (neighborX < 0 || neighborX >= mapWidth) { 
        continue;
    }
    for (var neighborY = y - 1; neighborY <= y + 1; neighborY += 2) { 
        if (neighborY < 0 || neighborY >= mapWidth) { 
            continue;
        } 
        currentCell.addClass('cell-grey').css('opacity', '1');
    } 
}
```

I'm not sure exactly what you're trying to accomplish, but it looks like there are other bugs in your code. You probably don't want to `return` immediately after turning a cell gray, for example. If you want each of the diagonal neighbors to turn gray, the loop above should do the trick.

This line near the beginning of your code contains a subtle error:

```
if (x < 0 || y < 0 || x > mapWidth || y > mapWidth) {
```

Valid indices range from `0` through `mapWidth - 1`, so you should write:

```
if (x < 0 || y < 0 || x >= mapWidth || y >= mapWidth) {
```

Comment: Thanks @MichaelLaszlo, I understand the iteration, but can you explain please, why `neighborX` and `neighborY` should be less then zero?

Comment: They should *not* be less than zero. Hence the `continue` statement, which skips the remainder of the loop body.